# How do you adjust the position of the megamenu in the Helix II framework

Tags: joomla-3.3.x

Trying to use the Helix II framework with Joomla 3.3.6. My main menu is in the default menu position, and that is good, but I would like it to float right. I see how to add a pull-right class to div#sp-menu but that doesn't work. Can anyone tell me how to add the pull-right class to div#sp-main-menu? That is one layer deeper in the tree. Is that even configurable?

I guess I could add a custom js with a little jQuery to do the trick, but I would prefer this to be configured some way.

Comment: Hi jmarkmurphy. Welcome to JSE. It sounds like you could solve your problem with CSS. Can you provide us with more information (such as live link/template/css/etc)?

Comment: Unfortunately we ca't really help without seeing a live preview of the site or some code to replicate what you currently have. Could you please provide one of these?

Comment: @moomoochoo - yes, I believe I could solve it with the right bit of css as I stated in the post, but I am unable to determine where in the Helix II framework configuration or code to add the change.

Comment: @lodder - Here is the test site http://test.swocc.org. The menu at the top of the page, I want it to float right. Looking at it in the code inspector in chrome, I can see where to put the pull-right class, but I can't find the way to get that class in where I want it. The Helix II documentation doesn't help at all.

Comment: Try opening the menu module in the Joomla backend and adding ` pull-right` as the *Module Class Suffix*. Make sure there is a space before the class name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to do this. I consider it a little sub-optimal, but editing the module Class Suffix as @Lodder suggested did not work becase the main menu in the Helix framework is not a menu module, and in fact I have that module unpublished. To fix this, I had to edit a template file.

This happens in the backend:

1. Navigate to Extensions - Template Manager
2. Find the Style you want to update, and click it's template in the Template column - This should be sharper_helix_ii.
3. Open the less folder.
4. Edit the menu.less file.
5. Near the top of the file add `float:right;` to the #sp-main-menu selector as shown below.

```
    /* Menu */
    #sp-main-menu {
       float:right;
```

Comment: if your answer solves the problem please select it as the answer. You can do that by clicking the tick next to your answer.